# Encryption for Database Items

Tags: php, mysql

Hi i am working on a small PHP project.

I have a table which is storing prices of items in DB(MYSQL). Is there any way the price table is hashed or encrypted in database, so server admin or even me cannot see the client price. its only visible in site after login in to system.

Using this can prevent if some one downloaded the Database and they can not see the transaction tables data

Whats the best recommendation?

Thank You

Comment: You can certainly hash data that does not need to be retrieved at a later data (e.g. passwords). I would not hash values that you actually need like prices though.

Comment: Yes i can hash passsword... But prices are need to see in admin site so i can not hash it... Any other method?

Comment: You *could* encrypt it but anyone that was interested enough in your data to obtain it in the first place will be able to decrypt it with enough effort.

Comment: Data can be encrypted using `key` and `iv` in `openssl_encrypt` before sending to database, then `openssl_decrypt` on retrieval. AES-256-CBC.

Answer (score 0):

You have to hard work about indexes, because encrypted data cannot be indexed so searching that row will not be easy.

**I recommended Aes :**

AES_ENCRYPT() and AES_DECRYPT() can be considered the most cryptographically secure encryption functions currently available in MySQL.

```
INSERT into user (first_name, address) VALUES (AES_ENCRYPT('Person', 'myword'),AES_ENCRYPT('Person', 'myword'));

SELECT AES_DECRYPT(first_name, 'myword'), AES_DECRYPT(address, 'myword') from user;
```

**Aes Encrypt Explanation:**

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-encrypt

**Aes Decrypt Explanation:**

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-decrypt

---

**All Mysql Encryption and Compression Functions :**
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html

**This article is best about Mysql Database Security:**

http://www.greensql.com/content/mysql-security-best-practices-hardening-mysql-tips